# Get XML paragraphs without nested tables

Tags: xml, r, ncbi

I'm parsing XML docs from PubMed Central and sometimes I find paragraphs with nested tables like the example below.  Is there a way in R to get the text and exclude the table?

```
doc <- xmlParse("<sec><p>Text</p>
  <p><em>More</em> text<table>
   <tr><td>SKIP</td><td>this</td></tr>
  </table></p>
 </sec>")

xpathSApply(doc, "//sec/p", xmlValue)
[1] "Text"              "More textSKIPthis"
```

I'd like to return paragraphs without the nested table rows.

```
[1] "Text"      "More text"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the nodes you dont want. In this example I remove nodes given by the XPATH `//sec/p/table`

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse("<sec><p>Text</p>
  <p>More text<table>
   <tr><td>SKIP</td><td>this</td></tr>
                </table></p>
                </sec>")


xpathSApply(doc, "//sec/p/table", removeNodes)
xpathSApply(doc, "//sec/p", xmlValue)
[1] "Text"      "More text"
```

If you want to keep your `doc` intact you could also consider:

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse("<sec><p>Text</p>
  <p>More text<table>
   <tr><td>SKIP</td><td>this</td></tr>
                </table></p>
                </sec>")
> xpathSApply(doc, "//sec/p/node()[not(self::table)]", xmlValue)
[1] "Text"      "More text"
```

or simply:

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//sec/p/text()", xmlValue)
[1] "Text"      "More text"
```

which is best will depend on the complexity of your real world case.

Comment: That's nice.  I wasn't yet aware of `removeNodes`

Comment: Yes its pretty useful in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful - I'll just need to get //table before getting //p in these rare cases.

Comment: If you dont want to delete nodes you can select nodes within `p` that are not `table` nodes.

Comment: There are usually lots of tags within the <p>, so I added one to the original question.  All these options are really helpful and in my case, I'll probably remove the table nodes so I can get back a vector with 2 paragraphs. Thanks again.